# How can I call "System.UnicodeString.UpperCase"?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Delphi documentation has [page](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.UnicodeString.UpperCase) for `System.UnicodeString.UpperCase`, but compiler refuses to compile it.

How was it supposed to be used?

Comment: Are you looking for `C++` or `Delphi`? You know you point to the documentation for `C++`?

Comment: I was looking for `Delphi language` function.
And, @SirRufo - no, I didn't know it's C++. It seemed to be valid `Delphi` function.
How did you know it is `C++` ?

Comment: I opend my eyes and read the whole page especially the `C++` tag on the left side of `UnicodeString   __fastcall UpperCase() const;` and did not find any `Delphi` tag on that page.

Comment: @SirRufo Oh, I had `C++` checkbox cleared in `Display preferences` (red box at top right) - that's why it was so confusing.
Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot call that method from Delphi. That method is only available from Embarcadero C++.

For Delphi the equivalent is [`SysUtils.AnsiUpperCase`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.AnsiUpperCase).

Comment: Note that `System.UnicodeString.UpperCase('myString')` (or `'myString'.ToUpper()`) has become available in later Editions of Delphi. XE4 if I'm not totally mistaken.

Comment: Those are made available via the RTL supplied string helper. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper